# How can I make generated content selectable?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I can have CSS display the ID for an element by using generated content, like this:

```
<style>
h2:hover:after {
  color: grey;
  content: "#" attr(id);
  float: right;
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: normal;
}
</style>
<h2 id="my-id">My ID</h2>
<p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et.</p>
```

How can I make that generated content ("#my-id") selectable so that the user can highlight and copy it?

Comment: But you can.
It's 'pointer-events: none;"
Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753590/pseudo-element-not-clickable

Comment: See this w3c issue as well: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2894

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can't make a pseudo-element selectable, as it doesn't exist in the DOM.

> **[5.10 Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)**
>
> Neither pseudo-elements nor pseudo-classes appear in the document source or document tree.

Comment: That's shame it's not possible :( Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: And yet, they are in the DOM in some sense, because they show up in the DOM inspector in browsers.

Comment: Right, when you see pseudo-elements/classes within the browser's DOM inspector, it is because the browser is emulating/simulating their presence (even though they aren't _technically_ there). Side note, I checked out that [w3c issue](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2894) you linked to and I completely agree that there are many use-cases where you would want to be able to select it.

Answer (score 7):

Pseudo elements are **not** present in the DOM. So you cannot select them.