# Pseudo-element not clickable

Tags: html, css

I've placed an arrow as an :after pseudo-element of a clickable tile. It creates a blind spot that is not clickable despite setting the height/width to 0.

Code here: http://cdpn.io/vpjCg

To see the issue, roll cursor over the tiled link, then over the character in the bottom-right corner.

Is there a CSS attribute or another solution to set the :after element as invisible to the mouse cursor so that the whole area is clickable?

Comment: You can't attach events to pseudo elements because they are not dom elements.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Pseudo elements belong to their parents - if their parent is clickable (`button`,`a`) then so will the pseudo element. Likewise with DOM elements, if a DOM element has a click event listener bound, it will be fired when you click directly on the DOM element, or on it's pseudo elements.

**EDIT**

In addition to my answer, you can make your clicks go "through" an element to hit underlying elements using the CSS property `pointer-events` and setting the value to `none`. Works in every modern browser (IE9 and up) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: Yes. correct answer. I can attach it to the anchor element instead of the div.item and all is good.

Thank you Adam.

Comment: The `pointer-event: none` style property saved the day.  Works in Firefox version 55.

Comment: Anyone else reading this- pointer-events: none; (notice 's' in events)

Comment: pointer-event: none,
so useful,
so unknown, thank-you. Works in mobile too