# Can text generated by pseudo-elements be made user-selectable?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I am digitizing a 75-page index of job competencies. Users need to be able to link to each competency, competencies are meaningfully grouped, and competencies are often a sentence long. So instead of using each competency's text as an anchor, I'm creating a labeling scheme and creating anchors for each item. The competency "Know your right hand from your left" might be given the label "E.1.A.2.2". This is tedious.

I'm trying to save myself from manually adding the label to every competency again (since I've already added it once in the anchor.) To show the label, I can use the pseudo-element `:before` to generate the label from the anchor, `{content: attr(name);}`.

That works nicely, but the generated text isn't selectable. To create a link to a specific competency, users will have to manually type in "#E.1.A.2.2", which invites more user error than I'd like to think about.

**Is it possible to make text generated by a pseudo-element selectable?** I'm open to other suggestions as well. If creating each label in HTML is the only way to get to the needed result, I'll do that. But ouch.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible. That text isn't even readable by a screen reader. I believe you'll have to go the JS route for your particular task.

Comment: I just came across this question which confirms my theory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914349/how-can-i-make-generated-content-selectable

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2651739/how-to-access-css-generated-content-with-javascript

Comment: Thanks, sorry my search-fu isn't up to the task today. @TylerH that question is interesting, though I've given up on incremental counters. I have no JS experience and can sort of follow the conversation there.

Answer (score 0):

To make it selectable and indexable by search engines I think *the only way* is to add content using JS

For example jQuery code:

```
$div.prepend("<span>My Text</span>")
```

Comment: It looks like our CMS's system loads jQuery 1.7.2, though I'm totally out of my element with jQuery. I only want to prepend the anchor name to the text of the link. So here's my example code from above:

`<a name="E.1.A.1.2">Know your right hand from your left</a>`

I'd like the result to be something like `<span class="label">E.1.A.2.2</span><a name="E.1.A.1.2">Know your right hand from your left</a>` for each of the hundreds of competencies in the index. Can anyone point me in a direction?