# Change color of Font Awesome icons when they selected

Tags: css, icons, selection, font-awesome, pseudo-element

Can I change color of Font Awesome icon using the `::selection` pseudo-element?

I used to do like that

```
.icon i::selection {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Or that:

```
.icon i:before::selection {
  color: #fff;
}
```

And other variations. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font Awesome icons are added using `:before`/`:after` pseudo-elements.

```
.fa-stack-overflow:before {
  content: "\f16c";
}
```

Since pseudo-elements [don't actually exist in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914349/how-can-i-make-generated-content-selectable/19914366#19914366), it's not possible to select them:

> **[5.10 Pseudo-elements and pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements)**
>
> Neither pseudo-elements nor pseudo-classes appear in the document source or document tree.

To work around this, you would have to avoid pseudo-elements and add the icon into the HTML directly, which isn't ideal. [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/r54r5dnw/)

Therefore `content: "\f16c"` would become `&#xf16c;`, which would have to be wrapped in a `.fa` element so that the correct `font-family` is applied: `<i class="fa">&#xf16c;</i>`.

For example:

```css
::selection {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
Selectable since it's added directly to the HTML: <i class="fa">&#xf16c;</i>
```

A more dynamic approach would be to use JavaScript to get the computed `content` value of the pseudo-element and then remove the pseudo-element and replace it with a unicode entity added directly into the HTML.