# Let user select pseudo element using mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello I have a html page which uses Pseudo element
We have set a selection class on the element to set background color red.

```css
div:after {
  content: " Me too !";
  position: absolute;
}
::selection {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Select Me.</div>
```

Please suggest how to make pseudo element selectable.

> > I can not change the current structure.

Comment: Pseudo-elements are not for content, only visual styling.

Comment: Yes .. But is there any way to fix it out

Comment: Don't use a pseudo-element?

Comment: I am bound to use this structure only :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make generated content selectable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914349/how-can-i-make-generated-content-selectable)

Comment: Can I use any javascript code for this ?

Comment: You could use JavaScript to add text and/or elements to the DOM yes. Accessing the pseudo-elements by JavaScript, no.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is that you cannot "select" a pseudo-element.

Long answer is you can fake it a bit by checking to see if a user has selected text in your div something like:

```
var element = document.querySelector('div');
var elementText = element.innerText || element.textContent;

element.addEventListener('onmouseup', function() {
  var selectedText;
  var afterText;

  if (window.getSelection) {
    selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type === "Text") {
    selectedText = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  if (selectedText === elementText) {
    // We've selected the div's text!
  } 
});
```

Then depending on how you want the behaviour to be, you could add a class to the element to style the ::after element differently, and then append the after element's content to the user selection via:

```
var afterText = window.getComputedStyle(element, ':after').content;
```