# Why can I select the text under a positioned pseudo element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have an element on which I use a pseudo-element (`::after`) to style an overlay. For technical reasons I cannot/don't want to use another element (e.g. `div`) to add the overlay. The pseudo-element is absolutely positioned and appears in front off the actual element. I was surprised to see that the text inside the `div` is still selectable, "through" the pseudo-element. I've played around with `z-index` and `pointer-events`, without success. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/womvfywy/1/) for an (external) example.

Why is this happening? Why can the text still be selected with the mouse? Is there any other solution apart for [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select#Browser_compatibility)?

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin dui nec neque rutrum, eu auctor nulla accumsan. Quisque non eleifend nibh. Fusce aliquet imperdiet odio vitae pretium. Nam tincidunt mattis ante, nec consectetur diam maximus
    vel. Fusce at lectus porttitor, feugiat purus sed, porta felis. Morbi tempus ante a orci finibus rhoncus. Nullam a porta enim. Sed id eros convallis, consectetur turpis a, gravida nunc. Nullam sed dui interdum diam placerat suscipit sit amet nec mi.
    Maecenas ultricies metus massa, id vestibulum nisi posuere facilisis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque blandit condimentum augue. Nullam pulvinar turpis libero, id luctus dolor ultricies quis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Not selectable when I "Run code snippet".

Comment: i can not select. using FF

Comment: Apparently the text is not selectable in FF. I can select it in Chrome/IE11/Edge15/Opera, on a Win10 machine.

Comment: You are missing `position: relative;` on the parent div. This affects the stacking index, and may result in the `<p>` tag having a higher stacking index than the `::after` psuedo-element.

Comment: @kunkalabs: No, it won't.

Comment: @BoltClock: Quite right - and not relevant to the problem, but probably worth noting as the snippet won't work as intended in a larger document.

Comment: @kunkalabs, you're right, it's missing from the example. I've updated both the fiddle and the snippet.

Comment: I would love to know whether FF is the only browser doing this correctly or the only one doing it wrong. Pseudo elements have always been a bit weird to me; I wonder if the HTML/CSS spec even has something to say on it at all.

Comment: Not sure why only FF applies the expected result - I could find no computed (browser) styles specific to these conditions.

Answer (score 4):

As for your question:

> Why is this happening?

It's seems to due to the fact that generated content itself is not selectable. see [How can I make generated content selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914349/how-can-i-make-generated-content-selectable))

Try selecting the text in the following snippet:

```css
div:before {
 content: 'generated content - before... ';
}
div:after {
 content: '...generated content - after';
}
```

```html
<div>Only content of div is selectable</div>
```

So apparently, selection is about selecting only elements which appear in the DOM and according to the [CSS 2.1 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-elements):

> Neither pseudo-elements nor pseudo-classes appear in the document
>   source or document tree.

So when selecting on the overlay - the overlay is ignored, and instead the text in the div is selected

---

That being said, [the spec here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#accessibility) seems to say that generated content *should* be selectable

> Generated content should be searchable, selectable, and available to
>   assistive technologies

...but to my knowledge that bit of the spec has not been implemented in any browser.

Comment: This makes sense, especially in the context of stacking rules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Stacking_without_z-index

Comment: Nice find. Thank you! This means that FireFox is the one "ignoring" the rules. Do you have a suggestion for the "prevent selection" part (other than `user-select` or `::selection`)?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use [**`user-select: none`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) an alternative can be to set as transparent the [**`::selection`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::selection).

```
p::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This doesn't just hide the selection but also make it impossible to highlight. It is compatible with [most of the browser](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3A%3Aselection) except mobile ones and Firefox (you have to use `::-moz-selection`).

```css
div::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.4;
  background-color: black;
}

p::selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}

p::-moz-selection {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sollicitudin dui nec neque rutrum, eu auctor nulla accumsan. Quisque non eleifend nibh. Fusce aliquet imperdiet odio vitae pretium. Nam tincidunt mattis ante, nec consectetur diam maximus
    vel. Fusce at lectus porttitor, feugiat purus sed, porta felis. Morbi tempus ante a orci finibus rhoncus. Nullam a porta enim. Sed id eros convallis, consectetur turpis a, gravida nunc. Nullam sed dui interdum diam placerat suscipit sit amet nec mi.
    Maecenas ultricies metus massa, id vestibulum nisi posuere facilisis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Quisque blandit condimentum augue. Nullam pulvinar turpis libero, id luctus dolor ultricies quis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you also have some insights that answer the interesting question as to  *why* the text is selectable in most browsers? What would be the correct behavior regarding the HTML/CSS spec?

Comment: The first thing I did on your solution was to drag the mouse over the text, holding the left mouse button clicked and then hitting `CTRL + C`. Can you guess the second thing I did? :) Still, a valid solution.