# Are "searchable, selectable, and available" in the pseudo element inconsistent?

Tags: html, css

I was searching for ::before/::after pseudo-elements and found this [description](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-content-3/#accessibility) ...

> 1.1. Accessibility of Generated Content
>
> Generated content should be searchable, selectable, and available to assistive technologies. The content property applies to speech and generated content must be rendered for speech output. [CSS3-SPEECH]

In another [place](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-pseudo-4/#intro) ...

> Since they are not restricted to fitting into the document tree, they can be used to select and style portions of the document that do not necessarily map to the document’s tree structure.

[and](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#pseudo-elements)

> Like pseudo-classes pseudo-elements do not appear in or modify the document source or document tree. Accordingly, they also do not affect the interpretation of structural pseudo-classes or other selectors pertaining to their originating element or its tree.

Is it consistent to ensure "searchable, selectable, and available" for something that is not mapped on the document and does not exist? If it is not in the document tree, it should not be selectable.

If the content has already been discussed (or concluded) in the CSSWG, I would you like tell me that where the topic was discussed, and how to achieve "searchable, selectable, and available" consistent with current specifications.

Or, if you have a better place to discuss this, please comment.

Comment: You should note that Pseudo element aren't only ::before/::after but also ::first-line for example

Comment: @TemaniAfif You're right. In this case, problem is related to the generated content, so I changed the focus to ::before/::after pseudo-elements for strictness.

Comment: None of "searchable, selectable, and available" are obviously constrained to the document tree. What makes you doubt its consistency?

Comment: @Alohci Are searches, selections, and other actions performed on things that exist in the document tree?

Comment: @Alohci related post: [How can I make generated content selectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19914349/12816933)

Comment: There's a difference between the current state of the art, and what is possible. "Searchable and selectable" are probably limited to the document tree at the current time, but there's no fundamental reason why that needs to be the case. That's kind of the point of the phrase that  you quote at the start of your question - that those actions need to be moved to be actions on the render tree instead. But that's a big change and hasn't happened yet.

Comment: On the other hand, it's not that radical. for instance you can't select or search parts of the document tree that are `display:none`, so browsers already take some account of the render tree.

Comment: @Alohci If the first quotation suggests that "the operation on the document tree needs to be switched to the operation on the render tree", then the specifications of each other seem to be consistent.

Comment: @Alohci And those comments seems being my question answer. Can you post those as answer?

Answer (score 0):

@Alohci 's [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012684/are-searchable-selectable-and-available-in-the-pseudo-element-inconsistent#comment106153378_60012684)...

> There's a difference between the current state of the art, and what is possible. "Searchable and selectable" are probably limited to the document tree at the current time, but there's no fundamental reason why that needs to be the case. That's kind of the point of the phrase that you quote at the start of your question - that those actions need to be moved to be actions on the render tree instead. But that's a big change and hasn't happened yet.
>
> On the other hand, it's not that radical. for instance you can't select or search parts of the document tree that are `display:none`, so browsers already take some account of the render tree.

If you have an answer, please post in addition to this for future reference.